# How to repeat for loop inside for loop with switch PHP

Tags: php, string, for-loop, switch-statement

I'm trying to repeat `$i` if it reach a certain number. For example `$i <= 4`, then start `$i` again, to get result like it should be below.

Code:

```
$let_a_p = '';

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
  switch (true) {
    case $i <= 1:
      $let_a_p = 'a'.$i;
      break;
    case $i <= 4:
      $i = 1;
      $let_a_p = 'b'.$i;
      break;
    case $i <= 8:
      $i = 1;
      $let_a_p = 'c'.$i;
      break;
  }
  echo $let_a_p;
}
```

Result should be:

```
a1
a2
a3
c1
c2
c3
c4
d1
d2
d3
```

(10 together)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you keep on resetting `$i`, which is controlling the loop.  Instead you could just adjust the number you display.  I've adjusted the switch conditions slightly to simplify it as well...

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    switch (true) {
        case $i < 4:
            $let_a_p = 'a'.$i;
            break;
        case $i < 8:
//             $i = 1;
            $let_a_p = 'b'.($i-3);
            break;
//         case $i <= 8:
//             $i = 1;
        default:
            $let_a_p = 'c'.($i-7);
            break;
    }
    echo $let_a_p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative and less error prone approach would be nested loops:

```
// model
$prefixes  = ['a','b','c'];
$limits    = [ 3 , 4 , 3 ];


// controller
$results = [];    // we want an array even if loop does not start at all
$c       = min(count($limits) , count($prefixes));

for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++)
  for ($j = 1; $j <= $limits[$i]; $j++)
    $results[] = $prefixes[$i] . $j;


// view
echo '<div>' .implode("</div>\n<div>", $results) . '</div>';
```

This is more general and follows MVC concepts.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks.